# Click on current tabItem of TabControl (in WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have ScrollViewer on my TabItem, what I want to do is when user touch header scrolling up, and I call this code

```
  ScrollMyProduct.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
```

But TabItem hasn't support clicking on only header of it, and SelectionChanged isn't work, because I clicking on current TabItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while back i did this changing the style of the header

```
<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content={Binding}>
                <Label.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="TabItemMouseDoubleClick"/>
                    </Style>
                </Label.Style>
            </Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Which bindings to the internal label of the tabheaders label item